# ServiceActivationException when deploying Flickr ECL Provider

Tags: ecl

I am working on ECL provider and for starter, I am trying to run Flickr ECL. I have done with all the steps provided in Bart's blog. I am getting Flickr icon on CMS but on clicking on it I am getting this error

> /WebUI/Models/ECL/Services/General.svc/GetList failed to execute.
>
> STATUS (500): System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException.

I have tried to search the same on net and there was a blog to change some settings in "Metabase.xml".

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you try admin user in <privilegedUserName>

Comment: I tried admin user as well as MTSuser. But both giving the same error.

Comment: Is it resolved?

Comment: this error was resolved but had another error after this which I mentioned below which again got resolved but again I am getting the second error since yesterday,msgAccessDeniedForImpersonationUser at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.EclService2012.AssertIsImpersonationUser(‌​String name) at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.EclService2012.InitializeUserContext(Stri‌​ng impersonationName) at CreateTridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.EclService2012() at ....

Comment: Error is very descriptive, as per issue in impersonation. User being impersonated is not having required permission.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding **msgAccessDeniedForImpersonationUser** at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.EclService2012.AssertIsImpersonationUser(‌​String name) 
error

Seems like Privileged user configured in ECL 
(`<PrivilegedUserName>` in MountPoint configuration)

should be impersonation user in CM `<impersonationUsers>`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of the needed Windows services
Is throwing an error.  Check the Tridion Event Viewer log for the details of the 500 error and post back here for additional input.

Comment: WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/62476613
 Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/WebUI/Models/ECL/Services/General.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The binding at system.serviceModel/bindings/webHttpBinding does not have a configured binding named 'Tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.WebServices.WebHttpsBindingConfig'. This is an invalid value for bindingConfiguration.

Comment: Looks like this is a standard WCF webservice configuration error.  See this post: http://puurunen.ca/blog/?p=169.  Are you perhaps running Tridion CM over HTTPS?  Your Tridion ContentManager config is most likely missing the HTTPS binding configuration, so you'll need to add it.

Comment: This is HTTP based CMS but it looks some binding/configuration issue for sure.

Comment: After resolving this, I am landed into another error: msgAccessDeniedForImpersonationUser
at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.EclService2012.AssertIsImpersonationUser(String name) at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.EclService2012.InitializeUserContext(String impersonationName) at CreateTridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.EclService2012() at System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext.GetServiceInstance(Message message) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceBehavior.EnsureServiceInstance(MessageRpc& rpc) a