# How to retreive ecl components using java or c# (using tridion core service 2013 sp1)?

Tags: ecl

I need to export the physical media files (using keepeek) stored as ecl items in Tridion for a data migration project. Any advice how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to consider that the files are not - contrary to what you write - stored as ECL items in Tridion. ECL items **reference** content on external systems.

As always there are several options, and which one is easiest depends on your skillset, the ECL Provider, and the keepeek API.

The simplest approach could be:

1. Recognize ECL stub components - they will have a title starting with ecl:, and they are based on the ECL stub schema.
2. Parse the keepeek ID out of the ECL URL - in most cases it will be pretty obvious what it is, but it might be escaped with ! if it contains naughty characters.
3. Call the keepeek API do read the data.

There is also an ECL API next to the Core Service. It is unfortunately a bit limited - It can't simply read the content of the external item (DAMs can be complicated and often there is not a single file behind an asset). Its primary use case is to browse external systems and add their content to Tridion - not the other way around.

But if your provider for example implement `FileItemData.DirectLinkToPublished` this could potentially point to the binary.

To access the ECL API:

Get the Tridion External Content Library API Reference from [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-2301148A-E3EA-43EF-A2FC-7D3C9BAEE8FF&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-2301148A-E3EA-43EF-A2FC-7D3C9BAEE8FF.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-2301148A-E3EA-43EF-A2FC-7D3C9BAEE8FF).

Remember to "unblock" the file after downloading or it won't open correctly.

The relevant documentation is in the `Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service` namespace, specifically the interface `IEclService2012`.

For details on how to set up the binding, see the answer to [question](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18111/not-able-to-use-ecl-service) (here it is done from code, you can of course also use configuration).

There is a precompiled client with the name `Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.Client.dll` already on your Tridion system, and I would recommend using it if possible.